# How to discuss between custom Polymer elements without events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

I would like to discuss between custom elements without events in a parent custom element.
How could I do this, if it's possible ?

This is **my-custom-parent-element.htlm** :

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-custom-elment-1.html">
<link rel="import" href="../my-custom-elment-2.html">
<polymer-element name="my-custom-parent-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <my-custom-elment-1></my-custom-elment-1>
        <my-custom-elment-2></my-custom-elment-2>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

this is **my-custom-element-1** :

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer-gestures/polymer-gestures.html">
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element-1">
    <template>
        <div><canvas width="300px" height="200px"></canvas></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function() {
                <!-- Here, I need notify my-custom-element-2 that canvas received an event without re-send an event-->
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

this is **my-custom-element-2** :

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element-2">
    <template>
        <div></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function() {
                <!-- Here, I need to change value by my-custom-element-1 notifications -->
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I would like to use a king of observer/observable system like [http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-observer/ ]

Comment: It seems strange to me that you would like to use an observer without events, when the typical observer is subscribing to events... That said, what you want may be done using two-way data binding (aka published attributes)... does this fit within your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure either how you want to do this.
But you can also give reference to elem1 from the parent :

```html
    <polymer-element name="my-custom-parent-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <my-custom-elment-1 id="elem1"></my-custom-elment-1>
        <my-custom-elment-2 id="elem2"></my-custom-elment-2>
    </template>
    <script>
Polymer({
            domReady: function() {
                this.$.elem1.target = this.$.elem2
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And in elem1 :

```html
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element-1" attributes="target">
    <template>
        <div><canvas width="300px" height="200px"></canvas></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function() {
                <!-- Here, I need notify my-custom-element-2 that canvas received an event without re-send an event-->
                  target.xxx();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But usually, the event way is better